# Firebase set(),push(),child() features

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing comments to movies. But with this code i just can add one comment. When i add second comment, the first comment changes with the second one. But i want to add more comments for my movie. How can i achieve that?
(show variable is my movie's id. My movie's id is one.)
The code is:

```
 btnComment.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                var movieComment = document.getElementById('textComment').value;
                set(child(firebaseRef, 'Movies/'+ show + '/Comments/'), {
                movieComment: movieComment
                });
      });
```

**My Firebase that i stored some movies**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a list of nodes in Firebase, consider using the `push()` method. To add a comment to the list with that:

```
push(child(firebaseRef, 'Movies/'+ show + '/Comments'), movieComment})
```

So we call `push` instead of `set` here, which generates a new child node with a unique ID under `Comments`.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [adding a child node to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) and this classic blog post: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: But this time im having a problem with retrieving them with their unique ID

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that @beytullahdanis. If that is related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70621866/firebase-adding-comments-and-getting-them), then please check and address my comment there.